# Django Form becomes Invalid When Field is Disabled

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am developing a django application for tracking a list of (music) albums that I've listened to, and when I've listened to them. I am trying to come up with how to render a form for creating a `Listen` (one of my models) for a specific `Album` (another model).

The relevant part of `Listen` is very simple:

```
class Listen(models.Model):
    """A model representing an instance of listening to an album.
    """
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listen_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, null=True)
```

I have a generic `CreateView` for creating a view with no pre-populated data:

```
class ListenCreate(generic.edit.CreateView):
    """View for adding a new Listen.
    """
    model = Listen
    form_class = ListenForm
    template_name = 'tracker/generic_form.html'
```

Then `ListenForm` looks like:

```
class ListenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listen
        fields = ['album', 'listen_date']
```

I've created a view that then is meant to add a listen *for a specific album*, where the album is deduced from an artist and album name in the URL:

```
class ListenCreateForAlbum(generic.edit.CreateView):
    """View for creating a listen for a specific album.
    """
    model = Listen
    form_class = ListenFormForAlbum
    template_name = 'tracker/generic_form.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = copy.copy(self.initial)
        # Get the initial Album using the artist/album names in the URL
        initial['album'] = Album.objects.get(
            name__iexact=unquote_plus(self.kwargs['album_name']),
            artist__name__iexact=unquote_plus(self.kwargs['artist_name']))
        return initial
```

Now, if I use `ListenForm` as the `form_class` for `ListenCreateForAlbum`, everything is fine, except that the field which selects the album is still editable. However, if I'm at a URL specifically for adding a `Listen` for a specific `Album`, I would like that `Album` selection to be fixed. So I created the `ListenFormForAlbum` form for the sole purpose of making it so the `album` field is disabled:

```
class ListenFormForAlbum(forms.ListenForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListenFormForAlbum, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['album'].disabled = True
```

This view renders fine, but when I try to submit the form, I get redirected back to the same form page with the following error displayed on the page:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

Why am I getting this message? Is there some way to get around it?

#### TL;DR:

I want to render a form for adding a model where a field corresponding to a different model via a `ForeignKey` relationship is pre-populated and disabled. The above is the closest I've gotten to some kind of solution--I'm able to pre-populate the field, but *disabling* the field so that it can't be changed causes an error on form submission.

Comment: values in disabled fields don't get sent to the server, since they're assumed to not be part of the form.  Options are to use CSS to apply a disabled class instead of actually disabling the field, or using a hidden input to send the value with the form submit.

Comment: @bryan60 Ah, thanks--this is what I get for trying to hack together a Django site without understanding the underlying protocols. I replaced the line in `ListenFormForAlbum.__init__` setting the field to be disabled with `self.fields['album'].widget = forms.widgets.HiddenInput()`, and added a separate HTML template that just displays which album the listen is being added for.

Answer (score 1):

Too late, and the OP seems to have solved the issue.

However, you need to pass `initial` dict, if you are disabling a field. Not sure if it's documented anywhere, but [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cb13792938f2c887134eb6b5164d89f8d8f9f1bd/django/forms/forms.py#L334) is the line that I'm referring to.